# Draw an ordinary plot with the same style as in plt.hist(histtype='step')

Tags: matplotlib

The method plt.hist() in pyplot has a way to create a 'step-like' plot style when calling

```
plt.hist(data, histtype='step')
```

[image]

but the 'ordinary' methods that plot raw data without processing (plt.plot(), plt.scatter(), etc.) apparently do not have style options to obtain the same result. My goal is to plot a given set of points using that style, without making histogram of these points.

Is that achievable with standard library methods for plotting a given 2-D set of points?

I also think that there is at least one hack (generating a fake distribution which would have histogram equal to our data) and a 'low-level' solution to draw each segment manually, but none of these ways seems favorable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `drawstyle="steps"`.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(10))

plt.plot(data, drawstyle="steps")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that this is slightly different from histograms, because the lines do not go to zero at the ends.

Comment: I think that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!